# Why is it that every time I steam vegetables while cooking rice my rice cooker ruins the rice?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker, steaming

Why is it that every time I steam vegetables while cooking rice my rice cooker ruins the rice? My rice to water ratio is the usual 1:2. My last two attempts included mushy basmati and jasmine rice. Luckily I was able to make rice pudding, but still what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your vegetables contain water. So in total there is more water than when you only cook rice. If you steam them, the water is released, so it's like you put more than 2:1 water in the cooker. Try reducing the amount of water a bit, until the rice is no longer soggy.

Answer (score 2):

Water in the vegetable releases as the vegetables are cooked.  If the vegetable in the rice cooker is in direct contact with the rice then the rice will get soggy. There are trays designed to use with rice steamer that sit on top the rice but will contain the water releases from the vegetable to avoid dripping onto the rice.